# How to add Tile-source with different projection to Map?

Tags: projection, openlayers-3

I use EPSG:3857 projection for View in Map. I can easily add OSM to my map. 
When I use  EPSG:3395 projection for View, I can easily add tile-layer with source in EPSG:3395(world mercator) projection.

But how to combaine on map tile-layers with different source projection(3857 and 3395) ? Is it possible in openlayers-3 ?
Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Not yet possible, should be possible around october when raster reprojection work has been finished.

https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3785

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer!